# Is there another way to write a function declaration?

Tags: javascript

It just seems odd to me to write dbr.onsuccess *after* dbr has been declared.

```
var dbr = window.indexedDB.open("Matrix");
dbr.onsuccess = function(myEvent) {}
```

Q: Is there an alternative way to write line 2 (without being Rube Goldberg)?  Maybe something like:

```
function dbr.onsuccess(myEvent) {
}
```

I'm just concerned about the order of things.  To me, it seems that it's too late to assign an onsuccess function to dbr *after* it's been created.

Comment: no! no! and once more, no!

Comment: lol.  I'm just an old school programmer.

Comment: hehe.. you cannot extend the base object 'dbr', in any other way, but to extend / add a property/method the way you did up above, just below the 'var dbr = window.indexedDB.open("Matrix");' :) Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var dbr = window.indexedDB.open("Matrix");
```

is an asynchronous request.

Async requests run in the background and won't run their callbacks until the function completes.  So all of the other assignments will happen before any callback functions are run.

The indexedDB is returning you an interface object so that you can define exactly what those callback functions are.  You can think of it as you making a request

> Hey I want to open matrix

and getting a response back saying

> Hey, I'm working on that, here's an object. Please list what you want to have happen when I finish on it.

Then, when it has completed the open operation (and the current function context has completed running) it will look at that object and run accordingly.

The return value of `open` isn't the real result of the function, its just an object returned for you to tell it what to do.  This is similar to a [promise/deferred](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/) way of doing things, which is different from the normal JS callback model.

This:

```
function dbr.onsuccess(myEvent) {
}
```

is not valid syntax.  You can't define a property on an object till the object itself has been defined, and javascript doesn't support function declarations for properties.  They're only used for top level objects.

Comment: "So all of the other assignments will happen before any callback events are run".  Oh wow!  That's good to know!

Comment: yep, this is a common misunderstanding with asynchronous functions.  If it helps, put some console.log statements in and see what order they're run.  One that you put in the function after the onsuccess function will happen before one put in the callback.

Comment: Right.  I understand that a callback comes back when it's done with it's task, but I didn't realize that the rest of the function would run to completion before the callback was even allowed back in.

Comment: @Phillip Yep thats an important thing to understand with JS.  Its single threaded and is only ever doing 1 thing at a time.  Events never "interrupt execution".  What you're currently doing will always finish and then it will move to the next event/function in the queue.  You can see that by using setTimeout(something,0).  Set timeout is async, so even if you set the timeout to be 0 it won't run till everything in the current function completes.

Answer (score 0):

```
dbr.onsuccess = function(myEvent) {}
```

This is technically a function expression, as it's an assignment statement to the `onsuccess` property of `dbr`.

So when you ask if there is more than one way to write a function declaration, the answer is technically no.

A function declaration has only one form:

```
function foo() {}
```

Your suggested syntax to declare a function as a property of an object is interesting but a wrinkle in the idea is function hoisting. As you probably already know, functions (including their definitions) available anywhere within scope, even preceding code. Take this example:

```
foo.bar();
var foo = getFoo();
function foo.bar() {}
```

Due to function hoisting, `foo.bar` should be available on line 1. But due to variable hoisting, `foo` is *declared* but not yet *defined*. On line 1 `foo` has a value of `undefined` and would result in a TypeError if you tried to invoke function `foo.bar`.

Comment: Oh.  I see why it's so confusing now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can say:

```
var dbr = window.indexedDB.open("Matrix").onsuccess = function(myEvent) {}
```